# Initializing Service and Repository Classes in Springboot Application Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I want to create a Springboot application where I am taking input from stdin, storing it into H2 db and showing results on stdout. Right now I am trying to do it in main application class after SpringApplication.run(), but it's not able to Autowire my Service and Repository classes. What is a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: use CommandLineRunner it's a good idea in your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access your beans by getting them from the application context after calling SpringApplication.run() :

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(...);
MyServiceClass myServiceClass = appContext.getBean(MyServiceClass.class);
```